# Resharper for huge projects, use or not use?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I've just asked my manager why our company does not use Resharper, and he, kind enough, told me that our projects are so huge to use Resharper, because it will slow our computers to their knees.

I'm still getting the source code from TFS, it seems to take 2 hours more(ahhh), each solution should contain about 30 projects, each project contains 50-100 .cs files. Our machines are running on Q6700/4GB RAM and Windows 7 x64 Enterprise, VS/TFS 2010 .

I'll try it myself, but I want to ask if Resharper (latest version) is suitable for huge project. Is there a change for me to configure/tweak VS/Resharper to get acceptable performance in my situation? Have you faced same thing?

Thank you very much

Comment: a bit out of subject, but is it an option to reorganize the code into smaller solutions ?

Comment: this thing is out of my privilege, further more, refactoring a huge solution to smaller solutions will take many man-days, which my boss definitely does not like!

Comment: @your_boss He should like it because it will make your software more valuable.

Answer (score 11):

I'd once to work on a project with 180 projects in the solution, with VS 2008, R#4 and only 2Gb of RAM.
The trick was to unload the projects from memory (right on the project in solution-explorer, then unload). I worked mainly with 5 projects and only they were processed by R#.
If I had to get a newer version of an unloaded project, I used the source control client (source safe for instance), then I ran msbuild.exe mysolution.sln in a command line console. This recompile the whole solution, in a background process without the full dev environment.

Comment: Wow +10 if I could. Just unloading some of my projects freed up dozens of MB of memory. Everything else is still fine, especially my unit tests still run fine. I have R# v7.1 to say.

Comment: This is virtually impossible to do in any reliable way. If you do any serious debugging, you need to move all about. Also, types from unloaded projects cause resharper (or VS2012?) static analysis to think they don't exist.

Seemed promising, at first.

Comment: It requires a good understanding of the whole solution. If you organize your solution well, you will know pretty well which projects are related to the one that you're working on. For e.g.: when you're changing the JavaScript files, you know for sure you don't have to worry about back-end and database project. So you can unload them.

Comment: @DioPhung, you're right. In my case, most of app areas were split into 2 or 3 projects. So I basically unloaded projects related to other part of the application I wasn't focusing on. Though, the app architect were stubborn and didn't admit a better architecture would have been benefical.

Answer (score 5):

Use Resharper no matter what. Your productivity is so much improved by it, that you can afford an insignificant performance decrease. It gets a bit sluggish with very big classes (500 lines+), but who in their right mind create those kinds of monster classes these days? :-)

Comment: Firstly, I'm an avid supporter of R#. That said, causing your system to move to the pagefile instead of memory can't be classified as insignificant.

Keeping in mind that other software must also be running on a system, and that it's possible that the developer might be working on multiple solutions (in multiple VS windows,) this is a real problem.

Comment: anyone at any enterprise company, ever

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions have been - in part - focused on speeding up performance, reducing the memory footprint and optimizing for larger solutions. While your case is rather extreme, in my opinion, you may still benefit from the productivity improvements. Just be wary opening huge code files - and TURN OFF "Solution Wide Analysis". =)

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to give you an exact answer to this. I've run into performance (memory) issues with Resharper in the past after some long coding sessions. Restarting Visual Studio often fixes this. My projects are perhaps not huge, so you probably run into this problem quicker than me.

However, I think the benefit I get in productivity using ReSharper vastly makes up for the performance loss.

If I were your manager, I'd rather spend a little more money on additional hardware and memory, than to spend money on ineffective programmers.

Comment: In my experience programmers are more effective without resharper. For once, they can be mobile and use laptops for development. Resharper needs a solid desktop with latest i7 6th gen double quad core, at least 32gb ram, and a very fast ssd drive. There are no laptops like these exist on the market.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I've always had problems with Resharper being CPU hog and memory intensive (and I do have Intel Core 2 Duo P9700 and 4GB ram and SSD drive). I even tried newest EAP 6.0 and on 2000 lines file (as being the only one open) it was taking 97% cpu (well VS was but without it there's no problem). Solution wide checking is turned off. It was killing productivity for me as I couldn't type fast enough and it was making me focus more on the Resharper then actual coding. The whole project has 120-160k lines so maybe this is the problem since on smaller projects Resharper was working like a charm.

Comment: Same problem here, I found resharper a productivity killer. Most of the time I had to wait 2-5 seconds for VS to come back when typing a key in code. On codebase less that 1k like of code. This is on quad core i7 / 8Gb RAM. Hardware requirements won't allow me to work on the go even on the most expensive laptop configurations. Jetbrains support is rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of R# performance tips:

- Turn off **Solution wide analysis** and run it only when you need: `Resharper` -> `Options` -> untick `Analyze errors in whole solution` and many more here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37228482
- In VS, unload projects that you know for sure you'll won't touch, or even better, have multiple solution that load only the project you need. For e.g: **All.sln**,**WebOnly.sln**, **ApiOnly.sln** (be creative).

Note 1: since you asked this question, hardware industry has advanced significantly. I'm opening a solution with 72 projects, 51,000+ files on a Macbook Pro with PCI-e SSD and it takes only 10-15 secs. Compile time is about 20-30 secs so I guess no problem so far.

Note 2: In 2015, Git >>> TFS.

Comment: f***ck that ))) buy resharper and disable it on certain projects or disable resharper features, where is a common sense in that?

Comment: you only do that if your solution is very big. There are always caveats working with large solution. It's up to you to not using Resharper , but I think the productivity gained by using Resharper outweight their drawbacks